# How to bind selected item in paper-menu (or dropdown-menu) to String instead of Number?

Tags: polymer

I have the following code:

```
<paper-menu selected="0" class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item name="KNJN">KNJN</paper-item>
    <paper-item name="GREEN_VIRTEX5">GREEN_VIRTEX5</paper-item>
</paper-menu>
<paper-input type="number" value="{{ settings.someItem }}" label="Some item"></paper-input>
```

I need to bind this to Object like this:

```
{
  someItem: Some number,
  someOtherItem: Selected item as string goes there
}
```

I've tried to use drop-down-menu with `selectedItemLabel` binded to the Object but this hasn't worked for me:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu selectedItemLabel="{{settings.boardType}}">
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item name="KNJN">KNJN</paper-item>
        <paper-item name="GREEN_VIRTEX5">GREEN_VIRTEX5</paper-item>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Also I don't know how to pre-select an item in dropdown-menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this... Since the menu uses the selectable behavior, you should be able to use attr-for-selected to set where the selected comes from:

```
<paper-menu selected="{{settings.someItem}}" attr-for-selected="name" class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item name="KNJN">KNJN</paper-item>
    <paper-item name="GREEN_VIRTEX5">GREEN_VIRTEX5</paper-item>
</paper-menu>
<paper-input type="string" value="{{settings.someItem}}" label="Some item">
</paper-input>
```

Comment: `paper-listbox` works like this. `paper-menu` did not. I don't know why